# Python requests gives a 200 response while FireFox gets a redirect

Tags: python, python-requests

Very simple problem. When I go to my Web site in any browser, it redirects. When I do a `requests.get(my_url)` on the exact same URL and protocol, I get a 200 response. Why? It doesn't matter if I set allow_redirects to True or False, I still get the same behavior. I tried setting a header so requests pretends to be Firefox, I still get the same behavior.

How can I get requests.get to give me the redirect that a browser gets on the exact same URL?

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python

import requests

result = requests.get("https://bgjkfgbjfgghbjdfbhdgfjkh.fake")

print(result.status_code)
```

The above prints "200".

Comment: Hard to say without the real URL...

Comment: The site is not publicly available so it wouldn't help you. It is the same as the URL I gave except with a different (internal) domain name.

Comment: Yes but the URL (and the user agent) are not the only things sent in a request. I'd suggest using Fiddler (you'd have to make Python trust its certificate) as Man-in-the-middle proxy to compare the exact requests sent by browser and Python and then manually play with those differences until you identify what causes it. I'd have done it for you, that's why I asked for the URL, but when it's internal, then you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Is the response content the same as expected or totally different ?

Comment: The response content is totally different.

Comment: @JeffWhite then given your comments ("result.is_redirect is false, result.next is empty, result.history is empty"), it's probably either a javascript redirect or a test on some cookie.

Answer (score -1):

from all your comments, it sounds like the status 200 is not signifying that the end page was fetched correctly (you say response.text is completely different in both cases - i.e. it isn't the end page you expect).

In this case, either:

- You are getting a simple 'click this to redirect' page, and the automated redirect that you experience from firefox is being implemented in javascript (which requets.get can't handle).
- Or the website is giving another 'error' page (without a 400 series error), due to something else missing, such as a cookie.

The fact that response.history is empty even when `allow_redirects` is True is yet more evidence that you are never getting the end page that you see in firefox, and that the 200 you are getting is not the end page, but a 'click here' or error page.

Comment: I think it is a javascript redirect of some sort. I'm not sure and I have zero control over the Web app. What do you mean by "response attributes"? result.is_redirect is false, result.next is empty, result.history is empty. The redirect is immediate.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers quite possibly ... I was concerned thet that amount of text needed wasn't going to fit into a comment - and my plan was to edit the the answer once clarification was received.

Comment: @JeffWhite - the requests.get returns a response object - do all of the attributes on the reponse object match what you expect from the first page, or the page you are redirected to ?